# Google Apps Script connect to Cloud MySQL database using Jdbc.getConnection()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Within GAS I am connecting to my GCP MySQL database via:
`Jdbc.getConnection()` as `Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection()` does not work for my case.

In addition I have tried to authorized the IP ranges as explained here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc
The GAS IP ranges are listed here: https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.txt

My problem: the list shows at the end a couple of IPv6 addresses, but the GCP MySQL database does only allow to authorize IPv4 addresses.
Any ideas? I thought about authorizing 0.0.0.0/0 which might not be the best option.

Comment: There have been a couple of posts I'm going to share related to this issue. Kindly check them out as they might give you some ideas. [Connecting to Google Cloud SQL with IPV6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247327/connecting-to-google-cloud-sql-with-ipv6) and [Add IPv6 To Google Cloud SQL Whitelist / Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371864/add-ipv6-to-google-cloud-sql-whitelist-authorization). Check the posts, answers and comments for hints.

Comment: Do not authorize `0.0.0.0/0` as it will open up your instance to the public internet. You'll lose an important layer of security. Cloud SQL does not support IPv6 yet so skip those IPs then try connecting. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @Dondi Yes it works without IPv6. Thank you.